# Garbled Code added to Email Field at 'Quick Edit' comment screen

Tags: email

when I edit a comment normally the email just contains the email like it should, but when I use 'quick edit comment' then there's code added in the email field after the email. This code to be specific:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */!function(){try{var t="currentScript"in document?document.currentScript:function(){for(var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute("cf-hash"))return t[e]}();if(t&&t.previousSibling){var e,r,n,i,c=t.previousSibling,a=c.getAttribute("data-cfemail");if(a){for(e="",r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16),n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)i=parseInt(a.substr(n,2),16)^r,e+=String.fromCharCode(i);e=document.createTextNode(e),c.parentNode.replaceChild(e,c)}}}catch(u){}}();/* ]]> */
```

When I then save the comment using the 'quick edit' menu it's saved like this:

abc@gmail.comCDATAfunctiontryvartcurrentScriptindocumentdocument.currentScriptfunctionforvar

Which is unwanted behavior of course...

I tried disabling all my plugins and removing all custom code from function.php but the problem still persists...

Anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's your server trying to obfuscate and protect the email address:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513190/cf-hash-attribute-and-script-mysteriously-added-to-mailto-links

Please speak to your hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks, will look into that and mark it this as the answer as it's resolved